# Inserting into table with a Default column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a table with a default column value `male`

```
CREATE TABLE Persons 
 (name varchar(20), 
  age int, 
  sex varchar(5) default 'male')
```

Insert statement #1:

```
INSERT INTO Persons values('Bob', 20)
```

Insert statement #2:

```
INSERT INTO Persons(name,sex) values('Bob', 20)
```

When I try to insert the values into `Persons` table using the insert statement #1, I get the error shown below

> column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

But when I insert into `Persons` using statement #2, it successfully executes.

Can some please explain why this happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, in your statement #1, if you *omit* the list of columns, you **must** supply values for **all three** columns, and you're not doing that. That's why it fails if you provide only two of those values.

And your statement #2 should probably be:

```
INSERT INTO Persons(name, age) values('Bob', 20)
```

and then you're clearly **specifying** which columns to insert into (`name` and `age`) and you're providing the two values required to fill two columns - that's why it works. The third column will be filled with the configured default, since you didn't specify anything for it.

For these reasons, I would recommend to **always explicitly specify** the list of columns you want to insert data into - don't just omit that list and *assume* that you're getting all columns right.....

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to write the fields, VALUES must match the number of fields in the table.

You can use DEFAULT four your purpose:

```
 INSERT INTO Persons VALUES('Bob', 20, DEFAULT);
```

Comment: True - this works - but I still think it's preferable to explicitly spell out the list of columns you're inserting into. This will break as soon as someone adds a fourth columns to the table ...

Comment: yes @marc_s , always is preferable take the control of the data that we are inserting. I add in the answer the DEFAULT clause only if you were interested to not explain all fields.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is failing because you are not specifying any of the columns in the `INSERT` statement. You are then only providing values for two columns instead of all 3 so it does not know what columns to put the values into...this won't work.

The second one works because you are explicitly stating that you want to insert into `name` and `gender` and you are specifying one value for each column.

The following will work (but I doubt you want `20` in the `gender` column):

```
INSERT INTO Persons(name,gender) 
values('Bob',20)
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO Persons(name,age) 
values('Bob',20)
```

I am guessing that you actually want to be inserting into `age` not `gender`.  It is very important that you explicitly state what columns you are inserting data into so you get the data in the right columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your table has 3 columns -

```
Name
Age
Gender
```

You have set a default for gender. In query (1), you are supplying 2 values for 3 columns, without a column list. Hence the error.

Raj